# How to utilise Sense UI widgets?

Tags: android

I was looking at my application (designed for 1.6) that uses the DatePicker controls on a HTC Desire the other day, and the owner of the phone showed me the native calendar program which uses much much nicer controls, i.e. the datepicker you can touch and scroll rather than having to repeatedly press the buttons to adjust days/months/year.

So my question is does anyone know if these sense controls can be automatically used in place of the stock datepicker controls?  I would ideally like my app to run on older devices i.e. 1.6 but show the nicer UI elements if running on a device that has the sense UI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well unfortunately it appears you can't.   Maybe if you know the widget classes you can use them but as for packaging them up in your app so you can rely on them being present in every phone you install on..  not a good idea... as you can't guarantee they'll even work on all devices...